# Как подгрузить разные формы в Blade Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, blade

Пишу шаблон в Blade на Laravel.

На странице присутствует `<select>` с выбором нескольких значений. 
Нужно, при выборе одного из значений, подгружать определённую форму на эту страницу (форма располагается в другом файле blade).

Как это реализовать? Написать обработчик в JS на событие в select и как то подгружать файл с формой на это место?

Только начал изучать blade в Laravel. 
наверное это очень просто вопрос, но до этого не реализовывал такое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я тоже искал подобное, но к сожалению blade не обладает подобной функциональностью. Подобное можно реализовать с помощью JavaScript и нескольких скрытых блоков в одном файле blade!)

Comment: В другом месте мне сказали юзать SPA, но я ещё не разбирался, что это такое))

Comment: Добавь меня в телеграмме) gagablik  , есть пару вопросов

Comment: Братан незнаю как добавить, напиши мне woskresk@gmail.com

Comment: Вчера написал уже) gagablik@gmail.com Либо скинь какой нить другой контакт)